# git will not register on VS Code, or in my activity bar?

Tags: git, windows-10, visual-studio-code

(Ignore the desktops on the right)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEIbt.jpg)

and when I try to change SCM providers:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SpzE.jpg)

There should be an icon that looks similar to the icon for **git-scm**. It's missing and I can't figure out how to add it, for easy git integration. **git-scm** is what the VS Code help docs refer to, so I don't want to have to use an alternative SCM.

The `git` command is successfully installed under PATH, and works from cmd or bash. How can I get the git section to show up under SCM?

Answer (score 1):

It's automatically added once you open a cloned project.

You can use vscode to clone the project:

1. Open vscode
2. Open command pallet (Cmd+Shift+P or Ctrl+Shift+P)
3. Write **"Git: Clone"** and run it
4. Paste your repo clone URL

For more information, you can check out [Using Version Control in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol)

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to do a clone. When you clone, VS Code finds the .git directory and the git-scm 'becomes available', that's why cloning works for activating the git-scm.

The reason you don't see the git-scm is because you don't have a git repository initialized. In your screenshot, you have a blank VS Code. Since there is nothing (no .git directory or anything) VS Code does not load the git-scm. VS Code does a 'lazy load' on certain extensions. So the 'git-scm' isn't getting loaded because the action that triggers it is the precense of a .git directory. Hence why you don't see the git-scm when you click on the version control icon in the activity bar.

You can do one of like three things. 1) Open the command palette on a blank VS Code and do a git init and select a folder for where you want to initialize an empty project or 2) open a project in VS Code and run the git init (if there isn't already a .git directory for that project) or 3) clone a project from within VS Code. Either of these options, after completing, you'll then see the git-scm, because it gets activated, when clicking on the version control icon.